# Getting wrong result when Integrating under an assumption

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

The simple integral

$$\int_0^b \cos\left(\frac{2\pi m(y-\eta)}{b}\right) \cos\left(\frac{2\pi \eta}{b}\right)\mathrm{d}\eta$$

can be easily evaluated by *Mathematica* as,

```
Integrate[
 Cos[(2 m π (y - η))/b] Cos[(2 π η)/b], {η, 0, b}]
(* (b m Cos[(m π (b - 2 y))/b] Sin[m π])/((-1 + m^2) π) *)
```

Due to the $\sin(m \pi)$ term this is zero whenever $m$ is an integer, **except** when $m^2=1$, when it evaluates to a something different,

```
Limit[(
 b m Cos[(m π (b - 2 y))/b] Sin[m π])/((-1 + m^2) π), 
 m -> 1]
(* 1/2 b Cos[(2 π y)/b] *)
```

This much is clear, but when I try to use `Assuming` on this integral, taking `m` to be an integer, it does not recognize this case and instead returns simply 0.

```
Assuming[m ∈ Integers, 
 Integrate[
  Cos[(2*Pi*m*(y - η))/b]*Cos[(2*Pi*η)/b], {η, 0, b}]]
(* 0 *)
```

the same occurs for `Simplify[]`

```
 Simplify[Integrate[Cos[(2*Pi*η)/b]*
 Cos[(2*Pi*m*(y - η))/b], {η, 0, b}], 
 Assumptions -> Element[m, Integers]]
(* 0 *)
```

An even more minimal example of the problem would be

```
Simplify[ Sin[m π]/((-1 + m^2) π), 
 Assumptions -> m ∈ Integers]
(* 0 *)
```

Why is this?  Is this a bug?

Interestingly, but somewhat unrelated to the above question, if instead of using `Assuming`, you provide an `Assumptions` to `Integrate`, via `Integrate[ Cos[(2 m π (y - η))/b] Cos[(2 π η)/b], {η, 0, b}, Assumptions -> {m ∈ Integers}]`,  it does not make this mistake.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question in this post. Only the announcement of a problem without sufficient details for anyone to make out what you want to ask.

Comment: @m_goldberg - the question could be rephrased to ask why `Integrate[
 Cos[(2 m π (y - η))/b] Cos[(2 π η)/b], {η, 0, 
  b}, Assumptions -> {m ∈ Integers}]` gives a different result than `Assuming[m ∈ Integers, 
 Integrate[
  Cos[(2 m π (y - η))/b] Cos[(2 π η)/b], {η, 0,
    b}]]`

Comment: @JasonB. Indeed it could, but can we be certain without more details from the OP that that is really the question?

Comment: @m_goldberg - no, we can't.  OP's question seems pretty clear (to me) to be "Why do I get the wrong answer from this integral when I use `Assuming`?"  But that's pretty localized, and is related to the question of why you get the right answer using the `Integrate[...., Assumptions->...]` form.

Comment: @JasonB. If you feel confident you understand the question well enough to answer, then please do so.

Comment: @m_goldberg I never said I could answer, I just helped to clarify the question.

Comment: obviously it is a *serious bag* and should be reported to Wolfram, this kind of integral was involved in many places in my  complicated calculation which appeared to be wrong now

Comment: "obviously… should be reported…" - so, did you actually send a bug report to them? Altho WRI employees sometimes post here, this is not an official channel for bug reports.

Comment: These problems with trig integrals have a long history here on the site, and the difference between `Assuming` and `Assumptions` has been discussed, too.  The integral is *generically* correct, which is all some solvers, like `Solve`, guarantee.  However `Reduce`, which is usually rigorous, gets the second wrong (`i0` equals the 1st integral): (1) `Reduce[y == i0 && m \[Element] Integers]` vs. (2) `Reduce[y == i0 && m \[Element] Integers, y]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's workaround, which is what one sometimes has to look for in those tricky trig integrals:

```
i0 = Assuming[m ∈ Integers,
  Simplify@
    DSolveValue[{A'[η] == 
       Cos[(2*Pi*m*(y - η))/b]*Cos[(2*Pi*η)/b], A[0] == 0}, 
     A[η], η] /. η -> b
  ];

e0 = i0 /. {m - 1 -> Sin[(-1 + m) π]/Sinc[(m - 1) Pi]/Pi, 
      m + 1 -> Sin[(1 + m) π]/Sinc[(m + 1) Pi]/Pi} /. 
    t : (h : Cos | Sin | Csc)[x_] :> TrigExpand[h[Expand[x]]] // 
   Expand;

goodQ = Quiet@Check[(# /. m -> 1) 0; True, False] & /@ List @@ e0;
good = Pick[e0, goodQ];
bad = Pick[e0, goodQ, False];

Simplify[
 good +
  ((1/(2 Pi)) Simplify@FunctionExpand[2 Pi bad] /. {m^2 - 1 :> 
      Sin[(-1 + m) π]/Sinc[(m - 1) Pi]/Pi*
       Sin[(1 + m) π]/Sinc[(m + 1) Pi]/Pi})
 ]
% /. {{m -> -1}, {m -> 1}} // Simplify

(*

-(1/8) b ((3 Cos[(m π (b - 2 y))/b] + 
      Cos[(m π (b + 2 y))/b]) Sinc[(1 + m) π] + 
   Sinc[(-1 + m) π] (3 Cos[(m π (b - 2 y))/b] + 
      Cos[(m π (b + 2 y))/b] - 
      4 m π Sin[(2 m π y)/b] Sinc[(1 + m) π]))

{1/2 b Cos[(2 π y)/b], 1/2 b Cos[(2 π y)/b]}

*)
```

Probably too much work: Sometimes it seems difficult to get *Mathematica* to do the things in trigonometry that are "obvious" to a human.